# Subir imagenes en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos para mostrar imágenes. Estoy ocupando preliminarmente XAMPP. Tomé un código de la web pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Creo saber donde está el problema pero no logro resolverlo. El código arroja un error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on resource...

Creo que el error está en:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album WHERE id=".$_GET["id"]);
```

En esta parte hay una comilla abierta en `SELECT` y creo que por ahí está el problema.

**Archivo principal**

```php
<body>
    <?php
    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","imagenes");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Error al conectar: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]) and (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]))) {
        if ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/gif" ||      $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/bmp" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png") {
            $info=getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);
            $imagenEscapes=$mysqli->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]));
            $sql="INSERT INTO `album` (anchura,altura,tipo,imagen) VALUES (".$info[0].",".$info[1].",'".$_FILES["userfile"]["type"]."','".$imagenEscapes."')";
            $mysqli->query($sql);
            $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
            echo "<div class='mensaje'>Imagen agregada con el id ".$id."</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='error'>Error: El formato de archivo tiene que ser JPG, GIF, BMP o PNG.</div>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <h2>Selecciona una imagen</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="POST">
        <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Guardar Imagen">
    </form>
    <h2>Listado de las imagenes añadidas a la base de datos</h2>
    <div class="listadoImagenes">
        <?php
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY id DESC");
          if($result) {
              while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                  echo "<img src='imagen_mostrar.php?id=".$row["id"]."' width='".$row["anchura"]."' height='".$row["altura"]."'>";        
              }
          }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Archivo para  mostrar imágenes**

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","imagenes");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("Error al conectar: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
header("Content-type:".$row["tipo"]);
echo $row['imagen'];
?>
```

Comment: Prueba con esto `$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 3):

Estás mezclando APIs. Piensas que estás usando `mysqli` pero en realidad estás usando la API **obsoleta** `mysql`.

La forma de obtener una conexión `mysqli` es así:

```
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```

Ahora ya puedes realizar consultas:

```
$connection->query('SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY id DESC'); // correcto
```

#### Actualización

Para mostrar la imagen en la vista tienes dos opciones:

- UUID
- Base64 (si las guardas en la base de datos)

En tu caso la elección es `Base64`:

```
echo base64_encode($row['imagen']);
```

Y muestras la imagen así:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,AQUI_LA_BASE64" />
```

Comment: Te refieres a la versión más reciente de XAMPP?

Comment: Me refiero al módulo `mysql` de PHP que ha sido declarado **obsoleto** a partir de PHP 5.5. Debes usar el nuevo módulo `mysqli`. Mirate la documentación.

Comment: Y eliminado completamente a partir de PHP 7. Puedes leer más sobre el tema en la [página oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, Alvaro.

Comment: Gracias, estaba un poco atrasado...

Comment: He actualizado el código. Ya no tengo el error, pero no logro mostrar las imágenes correctamente.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta para tratar eso.

Comment: Gracias. Base64 es un codificador de imagen, verdad?

Comment: Base64 es en realidad un [sistema de numeración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). No se usa solo para imágenes, también en algunos protocolos.

Comment: No sé si te entiendo bien; tendría que reemplazar   `echo "<img src='imagen_mostrar.php?id=".$row["id"]."' width='".$row["anchura"]."' height='".$row["altura"]."'>";`   por   `<img src="data:image/png;base64,AQUI_LA_BASE64" />`   donde BASE64 es una variable para capturar la numeración?

Comment: Supongamos que envías a la vista  la imagen en base64 en una variable `$photo`. Entonces sería: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?=$photo?>" />`. Si estás usando AJAX y estás haciendo `echo base64_encode($row['imagen']);` entonces en el success harías: `var img = document.getElementById('imagen'); img.src= 'data:image/png;base64,' + imgbase64;`

Comment: Lamentablemente no conozco AJAX, nunca lo he usado. Voy a intentar hacer lo mismo (mostrar imágenes) desde una carpeta, no desde una base de datos. He visto que funciona mejor. Gracias de todas maneras.