# ¿Por qué no me deja subir imagenes al servidor?

Tags: php, html5, imagen, xampp

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="datosImagen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="imagen":></label></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="imagen" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><input type="submit" valve="enviar imagen"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$nombre_imagen=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$tipo_iamgen=$_FILES['imagen']['type'];
$tamagno_imegen=$_FILES['imagen']['size'];


$carpetas_destino=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/INTRANET/UPLOADS/';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$carpetas_destino.$nombre_imagen);

?>
```

Comment: Verifica si ese directorio UPLOADS tiene permisos de escritura. Ponle 777, o escritura para todos para ir descartando.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25128/subir-imagenes-en-php

Comment: Puedes verificar tambien en el php.ini que el tamaño maximo de una peticion post esté configurado en un valor adecuado

Answer (score 0):

> la variable de global `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` obtine el directorio raíz de documentos en el cual se está ejecutando el script actual, según está definida en el archivo de configuración del servidor.

```
// carpeta actual /var/www/html/upload/
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// se imprimira /var/www/html/
```

te recomiendo usar `dirname(__FILE__)` y validar que la carpeta exista 



    
    Page Title

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["enviado"])){

    $nombre_imagen=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $tipo_iamgen=$_FILES['imagen']['type'];
    $tamagno_imegen=$_FILES['imagen']['size'];
    echo $tipo_iamgen;
    $DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  // crear el slash o back slash osea / or \  dependiendo del sistema operativo
    $carpetas_destino= dirname(__FILE__) . $DS .'INTRANET'.$DS.'UPLOADS'.$DS;
    $nombre_final = $carpetas_destino.$nombre_imagen;

    if (!file_exists($carpetas_destino)) {           // valida que existe la carpeta
        if(!mkdir($carpetas_destino, 0777, true)){   // valida que se cree
          die("no se puede crear la carpeta");       // termina la ejecucion si no se puede crear la ruta!
        } 
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$nombre_final); // mueve archivo a la ruta
    echo "archivo subido con exito<br>";

    //opcional para mostrar la imagen
    // $fichero = base64_encode(file_get_contents($nombre_final)); //carga la imagen
    // echo "<img src='data:.". $tipo_iamgen . ";base64,". $fichero  ."' width='200' height='200'>"; //muestra la imagen
}
?>


    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="1"> <!-- agregamos un input oculto para validar que se ah hecho un post -->
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="imagen":></label></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="imagen" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><input type="submit" valve="enviar imagen"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```